# Run python file Digital Ocean

Tags: python, python-3.x, digital-ocean

I installed python on a machine in digital ocean and cloned a repository with a file that was running on my local machine. But when I went to run the terminal by digital ocean he gave that error.

```
  File "teste.py", line 37
    print 'Total de marcas encontradas: '+str(len(all_brands)) 
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement is only valid in Python 2:

```
print 'Total de marcas encontradas: '+str(len(all_brands))
```

With Python 3, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) is a function, you need to add parenthesis:

```
print('Total de marcas encontradas: ' + str(len(all_brands)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You apparently switched to Python3.

```
$ python2
>>> print 'Hello' + str (len ('there'))
Hello5

$ python3
>>> print 'Hello' + str (len ('there'))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 'Hello' + str (len ('there'))
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```